# Global logger in Kotlin

Tags: logging, kotlin, singleton, kotlin-companion

I am currently working on a relatively large project in Kotlin. I would like to implement a logging method, however for many reasons (notably because I need a very specific type of clock management and a wide variety of appenders which will be a pain to implement in other frameworks), I cannot use typical logging frameworks like Log4J.

I would like - if possible - to be able to log from all classes without explicitly passing them a Logger object. I like the logging scheme that Kotlin-logging provides (with the use of a companion object), but it uses existing frameworks, which is a no-go.

In a way, what I need is some way to define a global logger. Any recommendations? Singletons and companion objects are probably part of the solution, but I don't really see how to build something handy.

Note: I need one of the appenders to write to ZMQ, so I would prefer to avoid instantiating multiple loggers.

Comment: Is it for specific framework (Spring, Android, ...)?

Comment: Not really, I'm building my own solution from scratch. I'm not using a specific framework (and I'm using the JVM).

Comment: If I understand correctly you could create a function in a file (without a class). Initialize the logger inside this function and call this function from any class.

Comment: That's indeed an idea. Let me try that...

Answer (score 3):

You can just define a top-level private val for the logger and access it from functions in the same file:

```
// Logging.kt
private class Logger(...) { ... }

private val logger = Logger(...)

fun log_debug(message: String) = logger.debug(message) 
// etc.
```

What this doesn't provide is class name for the logger, but it should be simple to combine with the Kotlin-logging scheme you mention to fix this if desired.